# nginx static files caching doesn't work

Tags: nginx, files, cache

here is my  conf file:
usr/local/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
location / {
root html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html
{
root html;
}
# serve static files directly
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|swf)$ {
expires 30d;
}
```

but it doesn't cache static files, how should I fix it? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            root   /var/www/u_1/public_html/;
    }
```